# IntelliJ GDSL provided with an jar

Tags: maven, groovy, intellij-idea, dsl

I have an library, published as a jar, at Maven repo, and this lib provides some Groovy DSL for user objects. Is it possible to provide [IntelliJ GDSL](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness) with this lib?

I mean, put it somewhere at META-INF inside a jar, or at Maven's `pom.xml`, and it will be automatically processed and used by IntelliJ IDEA?

Is there any way to make similar thing for Eclipse too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just add your jar with *.gdsl file to your library classes and the GDSL script will be executed in the user project automatically.